# Stripe recurring payment integrate with masterpass

Tags: stripe-payments, token, recurring, card

Is there any way to take recurring payment with **Masterpass** using Stripe?

Google pay and Apple pay can take the recurring payment with Stripe by returning the card token for stripe process. Is there any way to get card token like this with **Masterpass**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, you'd create a PaymentMethod with the data you get back from [Secure Remote Commerce](https://stripe.com/docs/secure-remote-commerce) (which is what Masterpass is calling itself now) and use that to start a subscription.

Follow Stripe's SRC guide, then when you get to the "[complete the payment](https://stripe.com/docs/secure-remote-commerce#completing-the-payment)" part you'd do something this instead:

```
  // create the payment method
  const pm = await stripe.paymentMethods.create({
    type: 'card',
    card: {
      masterpass: {
        cart_id: cartId, // your unique cart ID
        transaction_id: req.query.oauth_verifier, // get this from the SRC callback URL
      },
    }
  });

  // create the Stripe customer
  const cust = await stripe.customers.create({
    payment_method: pm.id,
  });

  // create the subscription
  const sub = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: cust.id,
    items: [{
      price: {{PRICE_ID}},
    }],
    default_payment_method: pm.id,
  });
```